# rspec testing subclass sti methods rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, single-table-inheritance

I am trying to build an rspec test for a method on an sti subclass and the test only reads the parent model's method.  The method works in the app, just not in the rspec test.  I can't figure out what I'm missing

models/animals/animal.rb

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base

  def favorite
    "unicorn"
  end

end
```

models/animals/mammal_animal.rb

```
class MammalAnimal < Animal

  def favorite
    "whale"
  end

end
```

models/animals/cat_mammal_animal.rb

```
class CatMammalAnimal < MammalAnimal

  def favorite
    "tabby"
  end

end
```

mammal_animal_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MammalAnimal, type: :model do

  let(:cat_mammal_animal) {FactoryGirl.create(:cat_factory)}
  subject(:model) { cat_mammal_animal }
  let(:described_class){"MammalAnimal"}

  describe "a Cat" do
    it "should initialize successfully as an instance of the described class" do
      expect(subject).to be_a_kind_of described_class
    end

    it "should have attribute type" do
      expect(subject).to have_attribute :type
    end

    it "has a valid factory" do 
      expect(cat_mammal_animal).to be_valid
    end

    describe ".favorite " do 
      it 'shows the favorite Cat' do
        expect(cat_mammal_animal.type).to eq("CatMammalAnimal")
        expect(cat_mammal_animal.favorite).to include("tabby")
        expect(cat_mammal_animal.favorite).not_to include("whale")
        expect(cat_mammal_animal.favorite).not_to include("unicorn")
        print cat_mammal_animal.favorite
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**error**

```
Failures:
  1) MammalAnimal.favorite and .favorite shows the favorite Cat
     Failure/Error: expect(cat_mammal_animal.type).to include("tabby")
       expected "unicorn" to include "tabby"
     # ./spec/models/mammal_animal_spec.rb:82:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

UPDATE

animals.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :animal do
    type 'Animal'
    name "dragon"


    trait :mammal do
      type 'MammalAnimal'
      name "zebra"
    end

    trait :cat do
      type 'CatMammalAnimal'
      name "calico"
    end

    factory :mammal_factory, traits: [:mammal]
    factory :cat_factory, traits: [:cat]

  end

end
```

as per a suggestion, I added the below line to the test

expect(cat_mammal_animal.class.constantize).to eq(CatMammalAnimal)

and got this error

1) MammalAnimal.favorite and .favorite shows the favorite Cat
     Failure/Error: expect(cat_animal_mammal.class.constantize).to eq(CatMammalAnimal)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `constantize' for #<Class:0x007f8ed4b8b0e0>
   Did you mean?  constants
```

Comment: what happens when you add expect(cat_mammal_animal.class.constantize).to eq(CatMammalAnimal) to your expectation above the failing line?  Also can you post your factory?

Comment: I've updated it, but I'm not sure what your looking to test with that new line.

Comment: Oops I guess the constantize bit.  My theory was that your factory somehow was creating the object with the correct type but the wrong class. Can you take the constantize part out and make CatMammalAnimal a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of using `trait` to create objects of subclasses, you should have separate factories for those too.

```
factory :animal do
  name 'dragon'
end

factory :mammal, class: MammalAnimal do
  name 'zebra'
end

factory :cat, class: CatMammalAnimal do
  name 'calico'
end
```

All of these can be defined in `animals.rb`

Then you can create your objects like

```
create(:animal)
create(:mammal)
create(:cat)
```